# Tensorflow image crop from bounding box

Tags: tensorflow

I am using the stanford dog dataset to do some image classification, loading with the following command.

```
dataset, info = tfds.load(name="stanford_dogs", with_info=True)
```

I want to crop using the bounding boxes available in the dataset and then resize the image to a standard size.

The following is my code to preprocess the data:

```
IMG_LEN = 128
IMG_SHAPE = (IMG_LEN,IMG_LEN,3)
N_BREEDS = 120

training_data = dataset['train']
test_data = dataset['test']

def preprocess(ds_row):
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = tf.squeeze(ds_row['objects']['bbox'])
    image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(ds_row['image'], ymin, ymax, xmin, xmax)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_LEN, IMG_LEN), method='nearest')
  
    # Onehot encoding labels
    label = tf.one_hot(ds_row['label'],N_BREEDS)

    return image, label

def prepare(dataset, batch_size=None):
    ds = dataset.map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls=4)
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    if batch_size:
        ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return ds

train_ds = prepare(dataset['train'],batch_size=128)
test_ds = prepare(dataset['test'],batch_size=128)
```

Here is the content of the dataset.

```
<PrefetchDataset shapes: {image: (None, None, 3), image/filename: (), label: (), objects: {bbox: (None, 4)}}, types: {image: tf.uint8, image/filename: tf.string, label: tf.int64, objects: {bbox: tf.float32}}>
```

When running the code, I get an error saying `OperatorNotAllowedInGraphError: iterating over tf.Tensor is not allowed in Graph execution. Use Eager execution or decorate this function with @tf.function.` regarding the following line: `ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = tf.squeeze(ds_row['objects']['bbox'])`

I don't understand the error, since I didn't specify to tf to run using graph. I am using tensorflow 2.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tf.data.Dataset` default to graph mode for performance reasons. In graph mode, you can't do tuple unpacking. You should use [`tf.unstack`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unstack) instead.

Note that your dataset has a variable number of bounding boxes. You can either consider only one bounding box per image, or write a preprocess function that is agnostic to the number of bounding boxes.

Note also that the bounding boxes of your dataset are normalized between 0 and 1, while [`tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_to_bounding_box) expects its coordinates (or offset) to be ints, with the format `(top, left, height, width)`

I would suggest to skip the tuple unpacking and to use [`tf.image.crop_and_resize`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/crop_and_resize) instead, that handle an arbitrary number of boxes per image.

### Fixing your approach:

This method will handle just 1 bounding box per image.

```
def preprocess(ds_row):
    image = ds_row['image']
    height, width = tf.unstack(tf.shape(image)[:2])
    # we consider only the first bounding box
    box = ds_row['objects']['bbox'][0]
    # conversion to top left + width height for crop_to_bounding_box
    scaled_box = box * [height, width, height, width]
    # using unstack instead of tuple unpacking
    ymin, xmin, ymax, xmax = tf.unstack(tf.cast(scaled_box, tf.int32))
    box_width = xmax - xmin
    box_height = ymax - ymin
    image = tf.image.crop_to_bounding_box(image, ymin, xmin, box_height, box_width)
    image = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(image, dtype=tf.float32)
    image = tf.image.resize(image, (IMG_LEN, IMG_LEN), method='nearest')

    # Onehot encoding labels
    label = tf.one_hot(ds_row['label'],N_BREEDS)

    return image, label

def prepare(dataset, batch_size=None):
    ds = dataset.map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls=4)
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    if batch_size:
        ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return ds
```

### What I would recommend:

This method will return as many images as there is bounding boxes in each image.

```
def preprocess(ds_row):
    image = tf.expand_dims(
        tf.image.convert_image_dtype(ds_row["image"], dtype=tf.float32), axis=0
    )
    bboxes = ds_row["objects"]["bbox"]
    # we only have one image, so all the boxes belong to the the first one.
    box_indices = tf.zeros(tf.shape(bboxes)[0], tf.int32)
    images = tf.image.crop_and_resize(
        image, bboxes, box_indices, crop_size=(IMG_LEN, IMG_LEN), method="nearest"
    )

    # Onehot encoding labels
    labels = tf.one_hot(ds_row["label"], N_BREEDS)
    # assuming that the multiple dogs on the image belong to the same class, 
    # as we get only one label
    labels = tf.repeat(tf.expand_dims(labels, axis=0), tf.shape(images)[0], axis=0)
    return images, labels


def prepare(dataset, batch_size=None):
    # we have to call unbatch to because of the variable number of bounding boxes 
    # resulting in a variable amount of images generated
    ds = dataset.map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls=4).unbatch()
    ds = ds.shuffle(buffer_size=1000)
    if batch_size:
        ds = ds.batch(batch_size)
    ds = ds.prefetch(buffer_size=tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE)
    return ds
```